# How to grab methods from window via Nightwatch.js?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a unique case where I need to expose functionality to our e2e suite. So, we've exposed functions like `performA` and `performB` on the `window` object. How could I grab these methods and objects from the `window` inside of `Nightwatch`?

```
browser
    .url(APP_URL)
    .pause(5000)
    .execute('return window.methods;', [], (res) => {
      const methods = res.value;
      // value exists, however, all of the methods are objects
      // so when I run the following method below, I get an error
      // 
      methods.performA()
    })
    .end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I should've been using `browser.execute(function)` rather than the string version.